# Custom table of contents typesetting for subsubsections

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to create a able of contents that looks like the following:

```
A chapter                                     page
   1 section                                  page
     1.1 subsection1                          page
         subsubsection1 - subsubsection2
         subsubsection3 - subsubsection4
     1.2 subsection2                          page
         subsubsection1 - subsubsection2
```

The subsubsection should be unnumbered and be displayed in a list that wraps around to consequent lines and should be separated by hyphens.

I succeeded with chapter and section numbering, but I have no clue how to achieve the subsubsection style. Any ideas?
For chapter and section I use

```
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I have clarified the style a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package for this:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\titlecontents*{subsubsection}
  [7em]
  {\small}
  {\thecontentslabel}
  {}
  {}
  [~---\ ]

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one one}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one two}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one three}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one four}
\subsection{Another test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two one}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two two}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two three}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two four}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two five}
\subsection{Yet another test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection three one}

\end{document}
```

### Update

In a comment it's been requested to add the page number after the title; here's one way to do it; I added a comma and an unbreakable space between the title and the page number (adjust according to needs):

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\titlecontents*{subsubsection}
  [7em]
  {\small}
  {\thecontentslabel}
  {}
  {,~\thecontentspage}
  [~---\ ]

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\subsection{A test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one one}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one two}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one three}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection one four}
\subsection{Another test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two one}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two two}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two three}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two four}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection two five}
\subsection{Yet another test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection three one}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, one additional question: how can I make the page number show up directly after each subsubsection?

Comment: @Philipp Hi. You're welcome. Please see my updated answer.